# Getting a Color from a String input

Tags: java

I am making an application where at some point i need the user to select a color, but as to not just have 50 radioButtons, I was wondering if it is possible to actually get the color they want from a textfield or something.

Comment: what about a select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier to just make a JComboBox or something alike?

But to answer your question: Yes it is possible. I'll give a piece of code that you could use as a start to get you going (assuming you still want the string to color)

```
String text = "red";
Color color;
Field field = Class.forName("java.awt.Color").getField(text.toLowerCase()); // toLowerCase because the color fields are RED or red, not Red
color = (Color)field.get(null);
```

Comment: Durr, I didn't think that trough. I guess I'll use a combobox instead.
Also, thanks for answering my actual question though, I might be able to use code alike in other situations.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use a `JColorChooser` that is a standard Swing component?

You can read a tutorial [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/colorchooser.html) but it is quite straightforward to use, as every Swing dialog, the result is something like:

[image: color chooser]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Color.parseColor(text);`

Answer (score 0):

you can always use a select box.

[info on how to create a JComboBox](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0240__Swing/CreatingJComboBoxComponents.htm)

Answer (score 0):

TRy

```
Color aColor   = (Color) Color.class.getField("white").get(null);
```

ALso,

See if the static method [Color.decode()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode%28java.lang.String%29) will serve your purpose.

Comment: Updated link to the `decode()` function: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Color.html#decode(java.lang.String)